# How can I add a library in Xcode which is in a hidden directory?

Tags: xcode4, linker, hidden-files

I want to add `libboost_filesystem.dylib` to my Xcode target as a library to link to, but Boost is installed in `/opt/local/lib`.

`/opt` is hidden and not accessible from the open panel, so I cannot select the dylib:

[image: screenshot]

How can I add the library to my target?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cmd-Shift-G in any open dialog under OS X triggers "go to folder" (in which you can enter any path). Alternatively you can `open /opt/local/lib` in the Terminal (which opens the folder in a Finder window), then drag the library into your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can first make the finder show all files.
Maybe "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true" will be worked.